# Which of given condition follows from mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:R \to R$ be differentiable which of the following follows from mean value theorem :

(a) For all $a,b \in R$ if $c \in (a,b)$, then $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$

(b) For some $a,b \in R$ and for all  $c \in (a,b)$, $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$

(c) For all $a,b \in R$ there is  some $c \in (a,b)$, then $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$

(d) For all $a,b \in R$ there is a unique element  $c \in (a,b)$,such that $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$

Now I know (c) is correct by mean value theorem,  For option (d) I can take $sinx$ over $[0,2\pi]$

the same example works for option (b) as well by taking the interval for any $(a,b)$.

(as there will exist only finitely many $c\in (a,b)$ such that $cos c = \dfrac{sin b - sina }{b-a}$)

However I am confused about option (a). By Mean Value theorem there exist at least on $c \in(a,b)$ such that $\dfrac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c)$ But the given option says if $c \in (a,b)$ then given condition must be true.

I don't know how to set a counterexample or prove it .

Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: For any $f$ that is not linear on $(a,b)$, you can find some $c\in(a,b)$ not satisfying that. In general you can prove this fact, but here you just need to take any $f$. $\sin x$ you wrote is also good. For almost every $c$ you will be given a counterexample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a) is true then $f'(c)$ has the same value for all $c  \in(a,b)$. You get a counterexample to this by taking $f(x)=x^{2}$, $a=0,b=1$.